# Is it possible to add a click event to the anything slider controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, anythingslider

I am using Anything slider in my website where I want to add a click event to the controls.
Is this possible? When I tried to do this my event is not triggering. Could anyone have idea about this?

My click event details:

```
 $(function(){
$('.thumbNav li a').click(function () {
$(".spec li a").css('color','#fff');
    });
});
```

fiddle link
[jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/5340](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/5340)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you code isn't working is because the navigation controls don't exist until after AnythingSlider has initialized. So, you really have two options:

1) Use your function within the `onInitialized` callback function ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/5375/)):

```
var tabContainers = $('div.spec-nav > div');
tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

$(function () {
    $('#slider1, #slider2, #slider3').anythingSlider({
        theme: 'metallic',
        easing: 'easeInOutBack',
        navigationFormatter: function (index, panel) {
            return ['Slab', 'Parking Lot', 'Drive', 'Glorius Dawn', 'Bjork?', 'Traffic Circle'][index - 1];
        },

        // Callback when the plugin finished initializing
        onInitialized: function (e, slider) {
            $('div.spec-nav ul li a').click(function () {
                tabContainers.hide();
                tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
                $('div.spec-nav ul li a').removeClass('spec-actv');
                $(this).addClass('spec-actv');
                return false;
            }).filter(':first').click();
        },

        onSlideComplete: function (slider) {
            // alert('Welcome to Slide #' + slider.currentPage);
        }
    });

});
```

2) Build this functionality when the navigation tabs are created... If you look at the [`navigationFormatter` documentation](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Navigation-options#navigationformatter-null), you'll see that you can return any attributes for the tab; this uses the [`jQuery()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements) of creating DOM elements.

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
  navigationFormatter : function(i, panel){
    return {
      'class'    : 'imatab',
      'data-hdr' : 'Header: ' + panel.find('h2').text(), // save text from the h2 in the panel
      'title'    : 'This text will end up in a tooltip',
      'html'     : '<a class="panel' + i + '" href="#"><span>' + ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bear', 'Wolf', 'Horse', 'Bjork?'][index - 1] + '</span></a>',
      'click'    : function(){ alert("AHHH I've been clicked"); }
    };
  }
});
```

And if you are using jQuery 1.8+, you can pass any jQuery instance methods like this:

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
  navigationFormatter : function(i, panel){
    return {
      class : 'imatab',
      on    : {
          click : function( event ) {
              // do something
          }
      },
      html  : '<a class="panel' + i + '" href="#"><span>' + i + '</span></a>'
    }
  }
});
```

I didn't make a demo for this method, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the JS console for errors? You have missed the `$` before selector inside the event handler.

And just in case, you can consider using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to bind events.

EDIT:

In your fiddle there is no element with class 'spec' - links `Tab#` are in div with class `spec-nav`. And the following code works fine:

```
$('.thumbNav li a').click(function () {
    $(".spec-nav li a").css('color','#f0f');
});
```

Check [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/5351/).

Comment: I miss typed that function check now

Comment: @Thejdeep do you have live demo of this somewhere? Or can you post needed parts of JS and HTML on jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/5340/ check this link but this is not the exact thing.I am pasting it for reference,look for thumbNav li a in this

Comment: @Gadzina See in the jsfiddle link i want to change the colors of tab1,tab2,tab3 differently.this is what i am trying to do.Here when we click on the tabs the slider rotates accordingly with respect to slide(with corresponding tab click).

Comment: @Thejdeep Check updated answer. And add your fiddle link to your question.